# c# SendKey to a hidden window

Tags: c#, process

I have a window which is hidden and I would like to send a keypress to it.  An example of what I'm trying to achieve is an app that will send the key F5 to a web browser which wasn't the active window.  The web browser would know to refresh the current page when the F5 keystroke is received.

I would also like to send a combination of keys to an application, e.g. Ctrl+S.  One example of this usage could be a timed auto-save feature to use with applications which don't have autosave.  This would spare me having to remember to save every 5 mins.

C# is my technology, does this sound realistic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SendKeys.aspx) article shows how to send keystrokes to an external application (with C# source code).

Answer (score 0):

You can use WinApi for this purpose. `SendMessage` or `PostMessage` method to send desired message to your application.

Here's C# definition of SendMessage

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(
    int  hWnd,     // handle to destination window
    uint Msg,      // message
    long wParam,   // first message parameter
    long lParam    // second message parameter
  );
```

and define the message that you want to send like:

```
public const uint %WM_MESSAGE_HERE% = %value%;
```

Check [PInvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SendMessage.html) - great resource containing WinApi method definitions for .NET

Comment: How would I, for instance, send Ctrl+F5 using your example (ie both keys pressed together)?

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible, look at [www.pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/) and search for [sendinput](http://www.pinvoke.net/search.aspx?search=sendinput&namespace=[All]), that page should tell you everything you need to know, also how to find the window (look for [findwindow](http://www.pinvoke.net/search.aspx?search=findwindow&namespace=[All]))